# Printing the counting of each word and the line number from a text file

Tags: java, data-structures

okay so this is has been confusing me for a couple of days, I need to read from a text file and print the number of time each word occurred which i managed to do it but I also need to print the number of lines where each word occurred also and that's where I'm stuck at thing moment, I don't need a direct solution because I want to solve it by myself but I need some help on where I should start or what to do next

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class PrintWordCounts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AVLTree<Word> tree = new AVLTree<Word>();


        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("AboutJUC.txt"));
            reader.useDelimiter("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");

            while (reader.hasNextLine()){
                String s = reader.nextLine();
                String[] words = s.split("\\s");
                int countLine;
                Word target = new Word(reader.next());
                Word result = tree.search(target);

                if ( result != null )
                    result.count++;
                else
                    tree.insert(target);
                    }


            reader.close();


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("File Error");
        }
            tree.inorder();
    }
}
```

and this the Word class the I'm using

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
    public String word;
    public int count;
    private LinkedList<Integer> lines = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    public int lineCount;

    public Word(String w) {
       word = w;
       count = 1;
       lineCount = 1;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Word other = (Word) obj;
        return word.equals(other.word);
    }

    public int compareTo(Word obj) {
        int comparedValue = word.compareTo(obj.word);
        while(comparedValue == 0){

            System.out.print(lineCount);
            lineCount++;
        }
        return word.compareTo(obj.word);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return word+"\t"+count + "\t" + "[" + lineCount + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get rid of infinite loop in compareTo. You need to use 2 cycles in your solution one for lines and nested for words in a line. Dictionary is more suitable than tree. In outer cycle create dictionary to count number of words in a line when you leave inner loop iterate through the dictionary and update number of usage in line by 1 for words in that dictionary. It should be enough info to complete the task I guess.

Comment: thanks you so much but I have no idea how to use HashMap

Comment: @Chsz have you figured it out how to use hash map? I missed your comment.. Actually dictionary and hash set are the same in terms of Java. So I updated my answer. You can use as key a string that represent a word and as value object of type Word. It will work faster with dict than with tree.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: add a line number counter. Let's call it `lineNum`. Initialize it outside the loop that reads line by line. After reading a line, increment its value.

Step 2: add a method in `Word` to add a line number, let's call it `addLineNum`. Use this method with `lineNum` when adding a word to the tree for the first time, and when updating an existing word, something like this:

```
if (result != null) {
    result.addLineNum(lineNum);
} else {
    target.addLineNum(lineNum);
    tree.insert(target);
}
```

Step 3: as there are multiple words per line, and you even created `words`,
you will need a nested loop to find those words.

Step 4: be careful with the line number adding and the matched word counting. There can be more words than lines that matched.

Comment: count is still required because a line can contain a word multiple times

Comment: Thank you for your help but shouldn't I use Step2 in my main?

Comment: @Chsz the method needs to be in `Word`, because it is a state specific to a an instance of word. Or, I'm not sure what you meant...